# Error solving an equation: TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sqrt method

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, equation-solving

I want to solve an equation using sympy but I'm failing.

The general syntax of the code worked before, its just failing with this equation. The equation Av_pv is only defined between 0 and 1, but all given variables keep it in this interval.

The Code

```
def Av_pv(pv):
    fac1 = 2 / (kappa - 1)
    fac2 = ((kappa + 1) / 2) ** ((kappa + 1) / (kappa - 1))
    return np.sqrt((fac1 * pv ** (2 / kappa) - fac1 * pv ** ((kappa + 1) / kappa)) * fac2)

x = sp.Symbol('x')
eq = Av_pv(x) - Av_e_2
pv2 = sp.solve(eq, x)
pv2 = float(pv2[1])
print('pv2:'
      '\t =', round(pv2, 2))
```

Full log:

```
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx", line 14, in <module>
    eq = Av_pv(x) - Av_e_2
  File "xxx", line 10, in Av_pv
    return np.sqrt((fac1 * pv ** (2 / kappa) - fac1 * pv ** ((kappa + 1) / kappa)) * fac2)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sqrt method
```

Comment: If I had to guess here, I would guess that you had accidentally created a global variable called `np` that is overriding your import of `numpy`.

Comment: im almost 100% sure that this didn't happen. I copied the Code into a new file to check that

Comment: Would you mind adding `print(np)` in that function, just to see what it says?

Comment: @TimRoberts seems ilke u were right. Using ** 0.5 instead of sqrt it worked

Comment: Don't use `numpy` functions like `np.sqrt` on `sympy` objects.

Comment: Well, you need `sp.sqrt()` to act on sympy expressions. Using `** 0.5` will make sure you stay into sympy's symbolic world. You can't use numpy or math (or mpmath of scipy) functions on sympy expressions.